# How to test services which use AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, mocha.js, angularfire, sinon

How services which use AngularFire should be tested?

Let's consider the following service:

```
app.factory("SampleService", ["$firebaseObject", "FBURL", function($firebaseObject, FBURL) {
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);

    return {
        get: function(id) {     
            var sampleDataRef = ref.child(id || "new");

            return $firebaseObject(sampleDataRef).$loaded();
        }
    };
}]);
```

I have created the following test, which should check if the firebase url is created properly and that the returned value is a promise. What is more, this test should not connect to the real firebase server. Unfortunately, it does not work as expected due to `$httpBackend` exception: *Error: No pending request to flush !*

```
describe("Service: SampleService", function() {
    var service,
        FBURL,
        $rootScope,
        $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(module("sampleApp"));

    beforeEach(module(function($provide){
        FBURL = "https://TEST_URL.firebaseio.com/";
        $provide.value("FBURL", FBURL);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($injector, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_) {        
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;

        service = $injector.get("SampleService");
    }));

    it("should get sample data by real id", function() {         
        var id = "SFO";
        var expectedResponse = {IATA: "TEST"};
        var actualResponse = null;

        $httpBackend.expectGET(FBURL + "/" + id).respond(expectedResponse);
        service.get(id).then(function(result) {
            actualResponse = result;          
        });
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(actualResponse).to.be.null;

        $rootScope.$apply();

        expect(actualResponse).to.be.eql(expectedResponse);
    });
});
```

My question is, how services which use AngularFire should be tested?

1. Does `$httpBackend` is enough to test described functionality? What should I fix in this test to make it work as expected?
2. Maybe instead of using `$httpBackend` I should create a stub and check arguments passed to it. I tried it with `sinon.stub()` method, but I can't make it work .
3. There is also [MockFirebase](https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase), but I didn't find any examples how to use it with AngularFire and mocha.

Full example created with mocha, chai and sinon is available on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ltowarek/dshrfv95/4/).

Comment: Yes, use $httpBackend. There are good examples of how to do this in Anglar's documentation. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: @lwalden I tried to use $httpBackend but it does not work for me as you can see in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ltowarek/dshrfv95/4/). In the console I can see the following warning: _FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (https://test_url.firebaseio.com)_ which indicates that the service connects to the firebase server. Also there is an error in the mocha output: _Error: No pending request to flush !_

Comment: There is also mockfirebase: https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase

Comment: And fingular for switching between mock (dev) and server (prod) Firebase https://www.npmjs.com/package/fingular

Comment: The [AngularFire tests](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/tree/master/tests) are also informative for both unit testing and e2e. As it stands, this question is primarily opinion based and requesting recommendations for tools. Please refine to show what you've tried and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Kato please check refined question